# In R, what does function() mean if you're NOT defining a function?

Tags: r

I'm using R for the first time to learn how to write classification algorithms. I'm mainly learning from the O'reilly book **Machine Learning for Hackers**.

There's tons of info in R, R documentation, ebooks, and my book about writing functions. However, there are snippets of code in the book that use the word function in a way that does not seem to conform to my understanding of the use of function. For example:

```
all.spam <- sapply(spam.docs, function(p) get.msg(paste(spam.path,p,sep="")))
```

where get.msg is a user defined function, sapply is from base `R`, and p is not defined anywhere in their code. There's no explanation in the book and I also tried searching and asking other R users in my company to no avail.

Any insight? Thanks in advance. By the way, in RStudio the word function is bright blue when used in this way.

Comment: You are defining a function, one that takes a `p` argument. You're just not assigning it to a name, so you can't use it again.

Comment: I don't know much about R, but this looks like a [lambda/anonymous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#R) to me. This could help you with your research :)

Comment: `sapply` is from `base` package! I suggest your learn some R tutorial to get the basics.

Comment: I suggest you do the same. sapply is from plyyr according to the 2 PhD's who wrote the book for O'Reilly. It may ALSO be in another package.

Comment: @user2121665: No it ain't. What is plyyr -- do you mean the `plyr` package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In R, you define anonymous and named functions using the same syntax, so your example:

```
all.spam <- sapply(spam.docs, function(p) get.msg(paste(spam.path,p,sep="")))
```

Is equivalent to:

```
my_spam_func <- function(p) {
  get.msg(paste(spam.path, p, sep=""))
}

all.spam2 <- sapply(spam.docs, my_spam_func)
```